# Is MouseEvent a class or an instance of a class or both?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having trouble getting the hang of as3 syntax (php is the only other coding language I know)

```
mybutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myListenerFunction);

function myListenerFunction(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     // function body
}
```

In this code it seems like MouseEvent is an instance of the class MouseEvent.

```
MouseEvent.CLICK
```

However in this code it seems like e is an instance of class MouseEvent

```
e:MouseEvent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MouseEvent.CLICK` is a class's public constant which can be accessed everywhere with no need to create an instance. It's like public static variable in php class.

`e:MouseEvent` is an instance of MouseEvent class.

Check out MouseEvent class documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html

Answer (score 3):

```
MouseEvent.CLICK
```

This is reference to a static constant of the MouseEvent class.  So to answer your question, MouseEvent here is a reference to a Class.  The CLICK Constant might be defined within the MouseEvent Class something like this:

```
package flash.events {
    public class MouseEvent extends Event {
        ...
        public static const CLICK:String = "click";
        ...
    }
}
```

So writing:

```
trace(MouseEvent.CLICK);
```

Would output the String:

```
click
```

Answer (score 2):

`MouseEvent.CLICK` is a static member of MouseEvent. It contains a string, which is the event name. You could also use `addEventListener("click", myListenerFunction)`, though that is less safe.
I guess they just needed somewhere to put that constant.

The MouseEvent-class instance contains information on what happened to trigger the event etc.